# Why is my app crashing when I allocate NSError userInfo to set a NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nserror

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Please, other format selected.", NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, @"This format is not available.", NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey, @"The operation couldn't be completed.", NSUnderlyingErrorKey, self.URL, NSURLErrorKey, nil];

NSLog(@"dict:%@", dict); // no Crash

NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"testError" code:1 userInfo:dict];// crash
```

why crashing when allocate error object?

---

Here are the crash details:

```
+[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3ebf5550
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC `NSUnderlyingErrorKey` is supposed to be another instance of `NSError`.

From the docs:

> The user info dictionary can sometimes include another `NSError` object
>   that represents an error in a subsystem underlying the error
>   represented by the containing `NSError`. You can query this underlying
>   error object to obtain more specific information about the cause of
>   the error.
>
> You access the underlying error object by using the `NSUnderlyingErrorKey` dictionary key.

Comment: sincerely, Thanks for your kindly answer.